# Use of multipart/form-data leads to 400 server error using flask, wfastcgi, IIS 6

Tags: python, flask, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2, wsgi

I've searched high and low for the answer to this question, and I'm at my wit's end.

I'm running a small web service on Windows Server 2008 using IIS 6. The web service is written in Python using Flask, and I'm using WSGI to interface between IIS and Flask. It's been working fine until I decided I wanted to allow uploading images. As soon as I put the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside a `<form>` tag, any attempt to submit the form leads to a 400 server error saying

> Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I've scoured the internet and no one seems to have had my particular problem before. The form in question looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="/log?case={{ CASE.id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="case_id" value="{{ CASE.id }}">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea><br>
    Case Status:
    {% if CASE.status=="Closed" %}
        <select name="status">
            <option value="Parked">Parked</option>
            <option value="Closed" SELECTED>Closed</option>
            <option value="Open" >Open</option>
        </select>
    {% elif CASE.status=="Open" %}
        <select name="status">
            <option value="Parked">Parked</option>
            <option value="Closed" >Closed</option>
            <option value="Open" SELECTED>Open</option>
       </select>
    {% elif CASE.status=="Parked" %}
       <select name="status">
           <option value="Parked" SELECTED>Parked</option>
           <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
           <option value="Open">Open</option>
       </select>
    {% else %}
       <select name="status">
           <option value="Parked">Parked</option>
           <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
           <option value="Open" SELECTED>Open</option>
       </select>
    {% endif %}
    <br>
    Computer Location:
    {% if CASE.location=="Owner" %}
        <select name="location">
            <option value="Storage" >Storage</option>
            <option value="Owner" SELECTED >Owner</option>
        </select>
    {% elif CASE.location=="Storage" %}
        <select name="location">
            <option value="Owner"  >Owner</option>
            <option value="Storage" SELECTED>Storage</option>
        </select>
    {% endif %}
    <br>
    <input type="file", name="image">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the request handler looks like

```
def handleCaseComment(form, files, case_id):
    # def handleCaseComment(form, case_id):
    # create SQLAlchemy session
    sess = db.session

    # get case comment information
    comment = form['comment']
    status = form['status']
    location = form['location']
    image = form['image']
    if image == "":
        image = None
    username = session['username']
    technician = Technician.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    case = Support_Request.query.filter_by(id=case_id).first()

    # create the case comment
    caseComment = Case_Comment(author=technician,
                               content=comment,
                               comp_loc=location,
                               comp_status=status,
                               case=case,
                               image=image)

    sess.add(caseComment)
    sess.commit()
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: First, the server is telling the browser, that it's a **browser** error, not a server error.  400 errors unilaterally mean "Hey browser, you messed up."  This is not a case of something internally broken, like accessing a field of a `None` variable, or dividing by zero.  Now, is that your intention?  Probably not, and I suspect it's a simple matter of enabling a filter somewhere.  Have you tried any debugging statements?  Does it ever get to your request handler?

Answer (score 0):

Plain old javascript, but here is a functional HTTP request from javascript to flask. Just tested it. I use it to upload images and then serve up thumbnails of those images back to the browser.

```
document.getElementById(configureFileDrops[0]).addEventListener('drop',function(event){
    files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    form = new FormData();
    form.append("index", "1");
    for (i = 0; i <files.length; i++){
        form.append("file" + String(i), files[i]);
    }
    form.enctype = "multipart/form-data"

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState ===4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
              //use response here
         };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", '<insert route>', true);
    xmlhttp.send(form);


},false);
```